# Cannot start process, the working directory '\c\Users\hazzaldo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpexejuk6bpycharm-management\setuptools-40.8.0' does not exist

Tags: python, pycharm

Everytime I create a new project with virtual environment `Virtualenv` option in PyCharm, when I click `create`, I get an error:

```
Cannot start process, the working directory '\c\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpexejuk6bpycharm-management\setuptools-40.8.0' does not exist
```

The project does get created, but I'm not sure what this error is!
I'm using PyCharm 2019.1.2 (Community Edition), on Windows 10 (64-bit).

Comment: Does your username have a space in it? Having a space (anywhere) in the path name sometimes causes problems on Windows, although I don't know if it causes a problem for this specific situation.

Comment: No my username is one word, no spaces, all lowercase and all just letters (no numbers or special characters).

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade your setuptools

```
pip install setuptools==40.8.0
```